# Can I ignore high multicollinearity in a proportional binomial GLM from a fully factorial experimental design dataset?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, multicollinearity, model-evaluation, ecology

I am running proportional binomial GLMs with 2 factors (Test Salinity and Region) but I am running into an issue with high multicollinearity. The reason for this is because this is a lab experiment with a fully factorial design where individuals from each region were spit up across 7 salinities - so each region will have the same 7 test salinities.

Therefore, I understand why I am getting high multicollinearity (since there is complete overlap of all the variables tested) but I am wondering if I can simply ignore this when looking at the performance of the model as this was a part of the set-up and can easily be explained -or- do I have to run some other kind of model to predict my proportional binomial response variable?

Comment: Region 1: salinities 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7; Region 2: salinities 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7; Region 3: salinities 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7; Region 4: salinities 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7; Region 5: salinities 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7; Region 6: salinities 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7; Region 7: salinities 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7. Why do you have any multicollinearity? Region and salinity should be totally independent of each other.

Comment: Can you show us a plot of salinity versus region? A fully factorial experiment would not normally lead to high multicollinearity?

Comment: you gotta run the regression at an individual level, such that there's only one salinity and one region per row of our X matrix and entry of your y vector